# Is there a workaround for this package load error?

Tags: r, package

I am trying to manually load a package in R using a binary file, as I am in a virtual environment without internet connection.

The install seems to be going fine, but when I try to load the library into an RStudio session, I get the following error:

> Error: package or namespace load failed for 'cli' in inDL(x,
> as.logical(local), as.logical(now),...): unable to load share object
> 'C:/Users//cli.dll' : LoadLibrary failure: The specified
> procedure could not be found.

This process has worked several times for other packages, but `cli` seems to be the only one that I've had this issue with thus far. I believe all dependencies have been installed with their most recent versions. Anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you come across issues with `.dll` files there are a couple of possible solutions:

- Ensure that your security/firewall policies have not quarantined the `.dll` file as this is quite common, especially on work machines.
- Delete the package folder in your `.libPaths()[1]` directory and re-install the package from a vanilla R session (i.e. `R --vanilla`)
- Lastly, ensure your machine has latest version of `rtools` installed and it is on your PATH environment variable (includes the necessary compilers for `C++` like `make`, etc. You can test this by running `Sys.which("make")` which should point to your rtools path `usr/bin/make.exe`